# Outlook Rule to flag unanswered emails after a specific amount of time

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, automation, exchange

The company I work for is slowly trying to re-structure our email system, specifically how we respond to emails sent to our main support distro. Now instead of pretty much everyone responding to support emails as they come in, only our scheduling department (2 or 3 people) are supposed to be responding UNLESS they can't respond to the emails within 15 minutes. Obviously, it's been pretty difficult to stay on top of that, especially because at least 2 or 3 emails a week were slipping through the net unnoticed when there were a dozen people paying attention.

So my question is, does anyone have any brilliant way to automatically flag (tag) an email for follow-up if it hasn't been responded to by anyone in the organization after 15 minutes? I've been poking around rule configurations and haven't gotten close yet, but I definitely think this is possible.

We're using the latest version of Microsoft Exchange (or close to it) and the latest versions of Office 365.

Comment: I've had a quick look around and it doesn't look like you can test for the email status with the normal rules system. You might have to write some VBA code to handle this. I would also be cautious of the portability of the ruleset.

Comment: The company I work for actually uses Autotask for our ticketing system, and they're working on integrating it with incoming emails so that tickets can be generated automatically, but I feel like that's a long ways away and will be far from perfect. Plus, we'll still have to see, acknowledge, and respond to emails, only then they'll also automatically integrate with our tickets.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not a build-in method for this. You may try some VBA code to achieve this.